# Pyodbc.drivers() returning an empty list on Mac

Tags: python, odbc, homebrew, driver, pyodbc

I'm attempting to access an SQL Database using sqlalchemy, but I seemingly don't have any ODBC drivers installed. I've followed Microsoft's instructions on installing ODBC drivers via Homebrew here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-2017

But still am turning up short. When I perform pip install pyodbc, it returns that it's installed. However, when I search for the drivers, I just get an empty list:

```
In[1]: import pyodbc
In[2]: pyodbc.drivers()
Out[2]: []
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you run `odbcinst -j` at a command prompt? If so, check the contents of the odbcinst.ini file listed as the DRIVERS... location.

Comment: DRIVERS location is: /etc/odbcinst.ini; the USER DATA SOURCES..: /Users/MYUSERNAME/.odbc.ini. When I go to the file path, no files exist. If I try to open it at the command prompt, I get an error stating no programs know how to open the file.

Comment: So if you try `cat /etc/odbcinst.ini` you get "No such file or directory"?

Answer (score 6):

> Some users encounter an issue when trying to connect after installing the ODBC driver and receive an error like: "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)". It may be the case that unixODBC is not configured correctly to find registered drivers. In these cases, creating a couple symbolic links can resolve the issue.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini /etc/odbcinst.ini
sudo ln -s /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini /etc/odbc.ini
```

The above works for me.
[ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: For M1 macs, the above symlinks might be invalid. This is because the homebrew directory on M1s is `/opt/homebrew` instead of Intel's `/usr/local`. Thus the paths should be adjusted accordingly.